# Pytorch error "RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors"

Tags: pytorch, lstm, stock

Im wanting to make an PyTorch Stock Predictor with LSTM

I need some help with an Error and i tried to modify some Things in the forward function but it still gives me the same error

But as Im almost at the end I get an weird error:

`RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx and cx should also be 2-D but got (3-D, 3-D) tensors`

My Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import csv

# Set the device to use for training (GPU or CPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


# Define the LSTM model
class StockPredictionLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(StockPredictionLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)

        x = x.unsqueeze(2)

        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out


# Define hyperparameters
input_size = 6  # number of features (date, open, high, low, close prices, and trading volume)
hidden_size = 64
num_layers = 2
output_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 100

# Load and preprocess the data
with open('stock_data.csv', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  next(reader)  # skip header row
  data = []
  for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)
prices = data[:, 4].astype(float)
data = data[:, 1:-1].astype(float)
data = (data - np.mean(data, axis=0)) / np.std(data, axis=0)  # normalize data
prices = (prices - np.mean(prices, axis=0)) / np.std(
  prices, axis=0)  # normalize prices

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(data))
train_data = torch.from_numpy(data[:train_size]).float().to(device)
train_prices = torch.from_numpy(prices[:train_size]).float().to(device)
test_data = torch.from_numpy(data[train_size:]).float().to(device)
test_prices = torch.from_numpy(prices[train_size:]).float().to(device)

# Initialize the model and optimizer
model = StockPredictionLSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers,
                            output_size).to(device)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  # Forward pass
  outputs = model(train_data.unsqueeze(0))
  loss = criterion(outputs, train_prices.view(-1, 1))

  # Backward and optimize
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

  if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
    print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs,
                                               loss.item()))

# Save the trained model to a file
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'stock_prediction_lstm.pth')
```

The `stock_data.csv` file:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2014-09-17,465.864014,468.174011,452.421997,457.334015,457.334015,21056800
2014-09-18,456.859985,456.859985,413.104004,424.440002,424.440002,34483200
2014-09-19,424.102997,427.834991,384.532013,394.795990,394.795990,37919700
2014-09-20,394.673004,423.295990,389.882996,408.903992,408.903992,36863600
2014-09-21,408.084991,412.425995,393.181000,398.821014,398.821014,26580100
2014-09-22,399.100006,406.915985,397.130005,402.152008,402.152008,24127600
2014-09-23,402.092010,441.557007,396.196991,435.790985,435.790985,45099500
2014-09-24,435.751007,436.112000,421.131989,423.204987,423.204987,30627700
2014-09-25,423.156006,423.519989,409.467987,411.574005,411.574005,26814400
2014-09-26,411.428986,414.937988,400.009003,404.424988,404.424988,21460800
2014-09-27,403.556000,406.622986,397.372009,399.519989,399.519989,15029300
2014-09-28,399.471008,401.016998,374.332001,377.181000,377.181000,23613300
2014-09-29,376.928009,385.210999,372.239990,375.467010,375.467010,32497700
2014-09-30,376.088013,390.976990,373.442993,386.944000,386.944000,34707300
2014-10-01,387.427002,391.378998,380.779999,383.614990,383.614990,26229400
2014-10-02,383.988007,385.497009,372.946014,375.071991,375.071991,21777700
2014-10-03,375.181000,377.695007,357.859009,359.511993,359.511993,30901200
....
....
....
```

I tried various types of `def forward` but still getting errors..

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace.